# Group by date and sum value of the top 1% percentile?

Tags: python, pandas

```
date        balance
2020-03-31   1000
2020-03-31    900
2020-03-31    800
2020-03-31    700
2020-03-31    200
2020-03-31    100
....
2020-03-31     20
2020-03-31      1
2020-03-31     0.3
....
2020-06-30   3420
2020-06-30   3000
2020-06-30   2000
....
2020-06-30     30
2020-06-30      3
....
2020-09-30  10000
2020-09-30   3000
..
2020-09-30      3
```

I want to group by date and sum value across those that belong to the largest 1% percentile.
I used

```
book2  = book.groupby(['date'])['balance'].agg([lambda x : np.quantile(x, q=0.99), "sum"])
```

but this is giving me a strange value...
Any idea how to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: What value? How strange? What did you expect instead? How about an actual [mcve] you can work out by hand?

Comment: balance, i meant. what is strange?

Comment: Do you want the sum above 99% within  each group?

Comment: Yes. The largest values that belong to the top 1%, so if given a specific date, values range from 10,000, 9,999, all the way to 1, i want to sum the largest 100 numbers (10,000, 9,999,.... 9,900).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search all values above the top 1% then sum them for each date:

```
df.groupby('date')['balance'].apply(lambda x: x[x >= np.quantile(x, q=0.99)].sum())
```

Comment: this is great. One strange thing is if I use  q= 0.9999, ">="picks up the top two values.. i had to change to ">"